# incompatibility in internal topic in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What’s the strategy/best practice when we encounter a schema (avro) incompatibility error thrown from an internal topic (`MYTOPOLOGY-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000006-repartition-value`) ? 
How do we solve this?

Comment: Maybe you would need to reset your application and delete the schema from the registry before restarting your application.

Comment: I'd loose all the data in the join-windows, right?

Comment: Depends on the retention time of your input topic. If it's larger than the retention time of the Join stores (default 1 day), you won't loose anything. It's hard to judge in general what the best strategy is. Maybe it's also ok to just delete the affected topic and schemas from the registry.